# Security configuration for Actuator Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

Recently I updated Spring Boot version from 2.5.2 to 3.1.5 , and previously i had this Security configuration

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to("health"))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request-> request.anyRequest().permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
```

This configuration would ask for authentication for Actuator endpoints except for **"/health"**
But new version of Spring Boot does not support this configuration , so I changed it to this

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request->
                    request.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
                           .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }
```

But this is not working, because I still see the login form when trying to access **"/health"**

I tried to replace  **HealthEndpoint.class** with **"health"**, but it also didn't help.

Maybe I wrote the configuration wrong, or maybe Spring has auto-configuration for Actuator endpoints .

Comment: Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) all `actuator` endpoints are placed under the `/actuator` path by default. path and based on it you have to rewrite `securityFilterChain`.

Instead of current one implementation just write something like next one:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request->
                request.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            );
    
        return http.build();
      }
```

And also dont forget to declare next one config into `application.yml` file:

```
management:
 endpoints:
   web:
     exposure:
       include: "health,info"
```

It is going to solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same in application.yaml but i have "include : *", because i need all of them
But even when I changed configuration to one that you provided i still see login form when trying to access any of actuator endpoints

Comment: have you set `"/actuator/**"` permit all yet ?

Comment: Yes i have this 
 http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request->
                    request.requestMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
                           .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );

Manage is because I changed it, could it be because of that change?

Comment: don`t override default path. Restore default one and retry.

Comment: Okay i set path to default "actuator", but i still see login form

Comment: just add one more thing to your `securityFilterChain`. `http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());` before `return http.build();` and also `.anyRequest().authenticated()` here is your problem, not in `/actuator/**` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In case you couldn't find out what was the issue, I was able to resolve it by removing `spring.mvc.servlet.path=` from my `application.properties` file. Apparently, since Spring Boot 3.1.6, Spring Security no longer ignores the servlet path. I suppose you could also rewrite the matcher to include the servlet path, but I haven't tried that.